# change event on form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with inputs, some of them has the class named validate, now I want to do some action if the value of any of this fields are changed, I tried this way:

```
$(".validate").each(function(i, obj) {
  if ($(obj).hasClass("text") || $(obj).hasClass("image")) {
     $(obj).change(function() {
      alert("some stuff");    
    });
  }
});
```

When I try to change the value of some input no event is raised but when I changed the value and try to submit the form the event is raised. My question is how to raise the event without submitting the form

Comment: When is that code executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input.validate').change(function () {
      alert("some stuff");    
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over eements with `.validate` class, checking whether they have class `text` or `image`, if yes attaching event handler to it.

so unless the element has the specified class, handler won't be attached. you can do it simly as follows :

```
$(document).on('change', '.validate', function(){
 if ($(this).hasClass("text") || $(this).hasClass("image")) {
   alert("some stuff");
 }
)}
```